Visual studio remote debugging. Error: should not be rooted in a drive
I'm trying to build a project on a remote machine (remote: Linux, host: Windows 11) using СMake. The configuration seems to be successful, but the following error appears:
"Error: file=//home/user/.vs/project/subproject/CMakeFiles/subproject.dir/./src/subproject.c.o should not be rooted in a drive"
Please tell me what could be wrong or at least in what direction to look for the error.
Thanks in advance.
Log:
1> Starting copying files to remote machine.
1> Copying 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\CMakePresets.json' to '/home/user/.vs/project/CMakePresets.json'.
1> Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:04s:565ms).
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'project-debug'.
1> Found cmake executable at /usr/bin/cmake.
1> /usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -Dtarget:STRING="project" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/home/user/.vs/project/out/install/project-debug"   /home/user/.vs/project/CMakeLists.txt;
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (33.2s)
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/user/.vs/project/out/build/project-debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Error: file=//home/user/.vs/project/subproject/CMakeFiles/subproject.dir/./src/subproject.c.o should not be rooted in a drive
Parameter name: file
Actual value was //home/user/.vs/project/subproject/CMakeFiles/subproject.dir/./src/subproject.c.o.```

I tried different Linux distributions, but the error remains.


Have you tried not copying the .vs directory?  Just copy the entire solution without the .vs and all the Visual studio generated files.  Then run the solution from W11 using the Linux file system.  It will be slow but it should work.

I will try. Thanks for the answer.

The only place I see this phrase is in a VS bug report for version 15.7 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cmake-vcpkg-problem-parameter-name-file-actual-val/224238
